# Sql query for calculating amount based on shiftno?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks like this:

```
shiftno     sno     Amount
  100         7       20
              8       50
  101         9       10
             10       30
             11       20
```

I tried with this query

```
select SUM(Amount) 
from example 
where shiftNo = (select (max(shiftNo)) from example
```

It shows result = 10, but actual result is 10 + 30 + 20 = 60. Which was belongs to shiftno=101

**How can I get total result of 60?**

Comment: You have tagged both sql server and mysql ??

Comment: For the example data provided 10 appears to be the correct result. Has the shiftno been entered or intentionally left blank/null for sno 10 and sno 11?

Comment: What is sno?  Is shiftNo really blank on the intermediate rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want the highest `shiftNo` use `limit 1`. 
 If you want all `shiftNo` and their `amount` then leave the `limit` line:

```
 select shiftNo, SUM(Amount) as MaxAmount
 from exmple 
 group by shiftNo
 order by shiftNo desc
 limit 1
```

Comment: @Filburt: You are right. I corrected it to output the hightest `shiftNo` and not the highest `amount`.